# Pytest isn't running tests in this one Python file

Tags: python, pytest, tdd

I cannot get Pytest to test anything involving this code. It always says no tests ran when I use the code below. I'm trying to just get it to test and from there I can tinker with the rest, I'm just a bit stuck on this and can't figure it out. The code runs well, exactly as intended it's just when I try to pytest with it that I'm reciving a problem.

```
    import datetime
    
    
    tday = datetime.date.today()
    balance = 1000.0
    amount = float
    transaction_list = []
    
    
    class Account(amount):
    
        def get_balance(self):
            print("\n  This is your account balance: " + str(balance))
    
        def deposit(self, amount):
            global balance
            amount = float(input("\n  How much would you like to deposit? "))
            if amount > 10000:
                print("\n  Do you want to swim in the vualt? ")
            transaction_list.append("You deposited " + str(amount))
            balance = balance + amount
            print("\n  You're balance is now " + str(balance))
    
    
        def withdrawl(self, amount):
            global balance
            amount = float(input("\n  How much do you wanna take out? "))
            while amount > balance:
                amount = float(input("\n  You don't have enough funds. Enter a new value "))
            transaction_list.append("\n  You withdrew " + str(amount))
            balance = balance - amount
            print("\n  You're balance is now " + str(balance))   
    
    class Transaction(amount):
    
        def transaction(self):
            print("\n")
            print("  " + str(card_number) + " " + str(tday))
            print("\n  Recipt: HM21-1926\n")
            print("\n  Account: Chequing. Primary\n")
    
            print("\n  Here is your transaction history!\n")
            for i in transaction_list:
                print(i)
    
            print("\n  Account Balance: " + str(balance))
            print("\n  Limited time offer: get a personal loan starting at Prime + 1.99%*")
            print("\n  Offer valid until September 2, 2022.")
            print("\n  Conditions apply & approval required. Ask us for details.\n")
    
        account = Account()
        transaction = Transaction()
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        mike_lane = Account()
        print(repr(mike_lane))
        print(str(mike_lane))
```

The code below is the code I'm trying to use pytest on. I don't know if there is something wrong with what I'm trying to test or if there is something wrong with the main code. I'm just starting out with programming and this is a bit complicated for me still (However, I have to learn to do this for the class so I'm not able to come back to learn TDD later on)

```
    import bank_program
    
    def test_deposit():
    
        account = Account(100)
        assert balance.amount == 1100
    
    def test_depos():
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            assert amount = Account("ABC")
    
    
    def test_transactions():
        account = Account(100)
        assert tday() >= now
```

Comment: This is usually an error with folder structure or naming. `In general, pytest is invoked with the command pytest (see below for other ways to invoke pytest). This will execute all tests in all files whose names follow the form test_*.py or \*_test.py in the current directory and its subdirectories. ` (from this link: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html)

Comment: What is the error? Can you please put the log in your question?